# Logstash cannot run

Tags: logstash

I cannot run logstash on my windows-10 machine. What I have done so far:

1. Unzipped logastash-oss-7.2.0.zip
2. Verified that I have java installed and on path via java -version:

   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
   openjdk version "1.8.0_212" 
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.212.04.2 (build 1.8.0_212-b04) 
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.212.04.2 (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
3. When I run in unzipped ./bin directory logstash --version

   "warning: ignoring  JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
   warning: ignoring   JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8; pass JVM parameters via LS_JAVA_OPTS

There is nothing in logs. What I am doing wrong, why there is no output ?
Another java programs runs fine and I have also set LS_JAVA_OPTS, but this does not helped.

Comment: You have to set a config, which composed of inputs and ouputs. The most simple ones are stdin and stdout. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html

Comment: @baudsp thanks, I expected some misconfiguration on my side